# Retrieve node name by it's ID. (D3JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, d3.js

I am currently trying to have a sort of "general" tooltip. In here, the name and some other data from the currently "active" node are shown. E.G. when a node with id 3 is the active node, the tooltip shows the name and, for example, distance (not link distance!) of the node with id=3.

However, I cant seem to select the given node.
I keep getting "SyntaxError: Document.querySelector: '#3' is not a valid selector"

Below is the code:

```
var currNode = 3; // The active node ID
var position = d3.select("#" + currNode).name // The data I want to show, e.g. the name
```

And then the variable "position" is shown in the tooltip using

```
var tooltip = this.svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", 25)
      .attr("y", 25)
      .text("Your current position: " + position )
      .style("font-weight", 550)
      .style("font-size", 18)
```

Does anyone have a (different) way of accessing the data of a given node?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can bind a data object to element with d3 `datum`: https://gist.github.com/hugolpz/824446bb2f9bc8cce607

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have seen this. However, I just can't seem to grasp my head around this. How would I retrieve only a given attribute of a node. E.G. how would I ask for the name of node with ID=3 using ```datum```

Comment: Let's say you have a data object, then you add an element, and then you bind the data object to the element. Your question is how to find the element in the DOM by ID stored in the data object?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I don't seem to understand. Could you maybe give a practical example of this? I don't mean the answer to my question, but a practical example of your comment.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to show some information about the hovered element in your tooltip. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. I am familiar with hovered tooltips. What I want is to "simply" retrieve an attribute of a node given it's ID. 
My node data looks like this:
``` {"id" : 1, "name": "Node 1"}, {"id" : 2, "name": "Node 2"}, {"id" : 3, "name": "Node 3"}```

Now what I want, is, simply put;
```var position = [IDofNode].name```

So I want the ```name``` attribute of a node with an arbitrary ```id``` to be bound to an variable. I am not hovering or clicking on a node, else I could have used ```this```.

Comment: Just posted an answer. I hope it's what you need... If not, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an object by **id** in array of objects:

```
const nodeName = nodes.find(node => node.id === id).name;
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is very close. This however returns ```[object Object]```, which seems to me that it simply returns the type of attributes of the node. How would I now progress on how to return a value of a given attribute? 
```var position = nodes.find(node => node.id === currNode)```
Thank you in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: OMG yes! Thank you. I can't believe I didn't try the ```.name```. Thanks, this works! I checked your answer to be the correct answer.